# Logstash filename as ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using a folder as input:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/ProjectName/Uploads/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "dev/null"
  }
}
```

and as output:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "manual_index_name" # want filename here
    document_type => "_doc"
  }     
}
```

I want the index in elasticsearch to be the name of the file being indexed. 
I've tried variations of this answer with no success as I am not clear on what it is doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156466/6483906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `grok` filter to find the last portion of the filename:

```
filter {
  grok {
     match => ["path", "Uploads/%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}" ]
  }
}
```

and then just use the portion in your index name `index => "%{index_name}"`

Comment: I follow the same pattern, but the index I got is just %{index_name} as a plain string. Could you please give a hint on how to solve it?

Comment: Same thing happen for me