# Elastiscsearch index as file name from Logstash - quotes issue

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

I want to have index in ElasticSearch as the name of an uploaded file. I followed the answer suggested here - [Logstash filename as ElasticSearch index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473121/logstash-filename-as-elasticsearch-index). However, instead of receiving the index as file name, I get the index of what is exactly between the quotes - %{index_name}. What am I doing wrong?

Update - my syslog.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
  udp {
    port => 514
    type => "syslog"
  }
  file {
       path => "C:\web-developement\...\data\*.log"
       start_position => "beginning"
       type => "logs"
   }
}

filter {    
    grok {
     match => ["path", "data/%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}" ]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
      index => "%{index_name}"
      manage_template => false
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

UPD 2 - Logstash output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/C:/ELK/logstash-7.6.2/logstash-7.6.2/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.9.0.jar) to field java.io.Console.cs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to C:/ELK/logstash-7.6.2/logstash-7.6.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-06-10T17:37:34,552][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-06-10T17:37:34,670][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.2"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:36,144][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 37 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values
[2020-06-10T17:37:37,535][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2020-06-10T17:37:37,704][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:37,752][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-06-10T17:37:37,755][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-06-10T17:37:37,838][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2020-06-10T17:37:38,020][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been created for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2020-06-10T17:37:38,025][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["C:/ELK/logstash-7.6.2/logstash-7.6.2/config/syslog.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x577ae8e run>"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:38,798][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,237][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"C:/ELK/logstash-7.6.2/logstash-7.6.2/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_029446dc83f19d43b8822e485aa6e7a4", :path=>["C:\\web-developement\\project\\data\\*.log"]}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,263][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,312][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main] Starting UDP listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:514"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,353][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,378][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,390][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main] UDP listener started {:address=>"0.0.0.0:514", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"65536", :queue_size=>"2000"}
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,404][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main] Starting server on port: 5044
[2020-06-10T17:37:39,665][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Also, the output, when log file was updated give me the line _grokparsefailure.

```
...
 "@timestamp" => 2020-06-10T14:44:11.390Z,
         "event" => {
        "timezone" => "+03:00",
         "dataset" => "logstash.log",
          "module" => "logstash"
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
        [1] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your full logstash pipeline. If you are getting `%{index_name}` as the name, you probably do not have a field named `index_name`, but to be sure you need to share your logstash pipeline.

Comment: I've added the syslog.conf. Please let me know if should provide more information

Comment: Is your grok working? You are using windows path in your file filter input, which uses backward slashes, \, but your grok is trying to match a path that uses forward slashes, /, this will never match and you will never have the field `index_name`, you need to change your grok. Also, index names have some [restrictions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-path-params) and using file names as index name, which seems to be the case, may not be a good idea.

Comment: I've changed the backslash. If the gork filter looks like so - grok {
     match => ["path", "data\%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}" ]
    } it results in error. If I use two backslashes \\, I get the error described initially. I understand that it is not the best way to have the index as file name, but that's what I need for now. Thank you for sharing this info though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following grok pattern in your filter.

```
grok {
    match => ["path", "C:\\%{GREEDYDATA}\\%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}.log"]
}
```

This will match any path that starts with `C:\` and will extract the name of the file and store it in the field `index_name`.

For example, for a `path = C:\Web-development\tests\filename001.log`, the `index_name` will be `filename001`.

If any of your files have a uppercase letter, you will need to use a [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) to convert the `index_name` to lowercase, you can't have uppercase letters in an index name, if you have a space in the filename you will also need to use the mutate filter to remove the space, you can't have spaces in an index name, those are some of the [restrictions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-path-params)

Comment: Still didn't work out. Even if a set the full path. It still shows my index name as %{index_name}. Could it be a problem with %{} placeholder? My file names don't contain capital letters or spaces.

Comment: No, the `%{FIELDNAME}` is needed, it is the way logstash can access the content of the referenced field. Try to run your pipeline with only the `stdout` output and without any filter, and update your question with this output, so we can see how logstash is dealing with your messages.

Comment: By the output you mean the one that I receive in the console?!

Comment: Yes, the `stdout` outputs to the console.

Comment: I've added the output to the question description.